# How do you pack circles into a circle?

Tags: algorithms, packing-problem

I want to know how many small circles can be packed into a large circle.

Looking at [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirincir/) it seems that packing is a non-trivial problem to solve.

My interest is practical rather than theoretical, so I don't really care about the absolute upper bound. I just want a good enough solution that doesn't waste too much empty space.

Also, I have a range of acceptable diameters for the small circles. So it's not necessarily a question of packing $x$ circles into $1$ circle, but packing $x, x+1, ... x+n$ circles into a circle, and seeing which one looks nicer. For instance, looking at EPC, $16$ and $18$ circles in one circle seems to be much prettier than $17$ - so even if I was looking for $17$ ideally, I would compromise by either using smaller circles or fewer circles instead.

So to solve my problem, I need a general, easily computable algorithm for packing $n$ circles into $1$ circle. I suspect this does not exist (otherwise EPC wouldn't). What about a general, easily computable algorithm that packs $n$ circles into a circle "well enough"?

Comment: Perhaps related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket or I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: What exactly do you want your solution to satisfy? I see nothing except the number of circles and you have no details about their radii, and you seem worried about "prettiness", which is rather ill-defined (sadly!). Can you be more precise?

Comment: If we suppose we have a circle of radius $R$ and we need to put inside circles of radius $r<R$, we in fact choose $r$ in the open interval $(0,R)$, which is uncountable set.

Comment: I would give my vote for some simulation that attracts (all) circles to origo, but makes them repel each other if they get too close to each other. This should make them automatically spread out to fill gaps angularly (I think). Not so sure it will fulfill the easy to compute criterion though.

Comment: @shaihorowitz You have misunderstood it, I want circles of equal size.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I want the circles to be packed into a larger circle of minimal diameter. If the "prettiness" is too ambiguous for you; take it into mean as much symmetry as possible. I think my examples demonstrate the point already, though.

Comment: @Superbest : Maximizing the cardinality of the automorphism group is a very mathematical statement.

Comment: How many circles you want to pack? On [packomania](http://packomania.com/), one can download the best known packing of up to 2600 circles in a circle. If your application need to visit all circle in a tour, data for tour with minimal length (i.e near optimal solution for the "traveling salesman problem") is also available.

Comment: @achillehui Up to a hundred, so that takes care of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

> So to solve my problem, I need a general, easily computable algorithm
>   for packing n circles into 1 circle.

Some remarks:

Assuming the $N$ small circles $c_i$ have radius $r_i$ each and position $u_i = (x_i, y_i)$ and the big circle $C$ is centered around the origin and has radius $R$.

Then a feasible configuration $u = (u_1, \dotsc, u_N)$ is one where

- F1: all small circles reside within the big one $c_i \subseteq C$
- F2: all small circles do not intersect $c_i \cap c_j = \emptyset$
  for $i \ne j$

The simplest algorithm would generate random configurations $u$ and check for $F1$ and $F2$.

One problem is, that if $C$ is choosen too tight, especially $\sum_i r_i^2 > R^2$ the algorithm might never find a feasible configuration.

Another simple approach is exhaustive search, trying all configurations. As this configuration space is continuous this is not really possible. However one might experiment with restricting the positions to some discrete grid. The problem here is the enormous number of configurations.

On top of this there might be optimality criteria, like minimizing the area of the bounding box of the small circles. Even then one might end up with lots of solutions, thanks to symmetry.

The next level is probably to try heuristic methods. E.g. simulated annealing, genetic optimization, ant colony optimization, force field methods, etc. etc.
Recently neuronal networks came back into fashion.

And finally there might be exact methods. For these I would search literature.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for your last option : literature. The rest sounds like a crazy algorithmic nightmare!

Comment: Yes using heuristics is not really satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just packing them on the boundary? (I'll explain what I mean below).

Let $C$ be the circle of radius $R$ and order your $N$ circles as $C_1,\cdots,C_N$ such that $r_1 \ge r_2 \ge \cdots \ge r_N$. Place $C_1$ inside $C$ tangent to $C$. Then place $C_2$ tangent to $C_1$ and $C$, $C_3$ tangent to $C_2$ and $C$, $C_4$ tangent to $C_3$ and $C$, and keep going until the circle tangent to $C_n$ and $C$ has to intersect $C_1$. Then just "keep going around" (letting $C_{n+1}$ be the unique circle of radius $r_{n+1}$ tangent to $C_1$ and $C_n$).

Of course, this algorithm is not optimal and doesn't always work, but "it won't waste too much space" if it works. If you had values of $r_i$ and $R$ and the remaining space was too big, you can always retry with a smaller value of $R$.

Hope that helps,